# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property (import data from 2 tables)

Tags: jakarta-ee

i want to select a result from 2 sql tables with this method:

```
@Override
    public List<Object> getAll() {

        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery("select a.idAccount, c.firstName, c.lastName, a.dateOfCreation, a.bonusPoint from account a ,customer c where c.identity=a.id_Customer and a.bonusPoint>=5000 and TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(a.dateOfCreation) >=60");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

and i want to display this query in a datatable so i use a datamodel in the ManagedBean:

```
public DataModel getDataModel() {
        dataModel.setWrappedData(gIftManagementRemote.getAll());
        return dataModel;
    }
```

in jsf page, i use a datatable but i don't know what i should put in "var":

```
<rich:dataTable rows="15" id="table" value="#{assignGiftManagement.dataModel}"
            **var**="?????">
```

so when i run this page i have this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: id_Customer of: tn.esprit.bankSprint2.persistence.Account [select a.idAccount, c.firstName, c.lastName, a.dateOfCreation, a.bonusPoint from tn.esprit.bankSprint2.persistence.Account a ,tn.esprit.bankSprint2.persistence.Customer c where c.identity=a.id_Customer and a.bonusPoint>=5000 and TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(a.dateOfCreation) >=60]
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
```

WHAT I'M SUPPOSED TO DO ?!

Comment: does you `Account` have an `id_Customer` property?

Comment: yes it have, the mapping between entities is implemented, i think that the error provide from the method public List<Object> getAll()